# Why is App Access Token different to AppID|Secret now?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, oauth, access-token

In the facebook docs, it says we can specify:

AppID|Secret

As the application access_token

However, when going to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/  the App Token is different. This is in the form AppID|Randomnumber

Which should we be using? The PHP SDK uses the 'Secret' version - do we need to adjust this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppID|AppSecret works and I use it outside of PHP.  It is the only way to publish to a users stream after their access token expires and you haven't prompted for offline_access.  The appId|randomnumber they show you on that page expire like regular access tokens where appid|appsecret do not expire.

Comment: Hi, from that page it's written `App tokens do not expire and should be kept secret as they are related to your app secret.`

Answer (score 6):

The app token is not APP_ID|APP_SECRET. The [FB docs says](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/#step1) that the app token may be obtained using the APP_ID and the APP_SECRET. You can achieve this by hitting this URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Comment: Taken from the Facebook PHP SDK:

    public function getAccessToken() {
    ...
      return $this->getAppId() .'|'. $this->getApiSecret();
    }

Comment: maybe the FB PHP SDK is not updated, but what I wrote in the post is the proper way to get an app access_token.

Comment: APP_ID|APP_SECRET currently works in place of / as an app access token, but this is not the documented behaviour and i recommend using the method outlined in this question to avoid problems later

Comment: In `grant_type=client_credentials` what credentials do i need to submit there?

Comment: @Prasad: Just the constant string "client_credentials".

Comment: Is it necessary that a user must be logged in for getting facebook page details?

Comment: It's still documented. On the page you linked "You can just pass your app id and app secret as the access_token parameter when you make a call"